# Connected wireless connection, but no wlan0. What's causing this?

Tags: wireless, conky, ifconfig

I'm connecting (to the internet) over a wireless connection (as in, it's already connected), but there's no `wlan0`. Output produced by `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:ff:35:06:9c:b3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:82:76:6d:ee  
          inet addr:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:82ff:fe76:6dee/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:245381 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:160579
          TX packets:274599 errors:16 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:193751818 (193.7 MB)  TX bytes:32692764 (32.6 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:409 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:409 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:31117 (31.1 KB)  TX bytes:31117 (31.1 KB)
```

The connection I'm "using" is obviously eth1. Just wanted to fix it, as a *great* conky script doesn't work (wireless network link strength indicator)

ps. `nm-applet` does show my wireless network link strength without a hitch.

Comment: Do you use ndiswrapper? Does the /etc/iftab exist?

Comment: Dayjay: No, I do not use ndiswrapper, and /etc/iftab does not exist on my system.

Comment: I think you have to edit the persistent-net.rules file then. Just follow the link chris posted.

Comment: Dayjay: No, it looks like you need to get Conky (or whichever process accesses the information) to run as root for it to get the stuff. Works that way, but I'd rather not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my question on the internet. Apparently, to get Conky (or anything else for that matter) to work with the Broadcom drivers, you need to run the application as the super user. So, to fix the problem, you'd:

```
sudo conky -d
```

instead of

```
conky -d
```

Also, the `eth1` / `wlan0` problem is specific to Broadcom drivers (and *is supposed to happen* with them)

Answer (score 0):

You can always rename your interface name from eth1 to wlan0. Instructions [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1199030&highlight=move+eth1+eth0). But I think the cleaner solution would be to pass the interface name to the conky script (if that is possible). Or possibly to edit the conky script so it checks for eth1 and not wlan0.

I'm also not sure how nm-applet would react to the interface name change.

Comment: changing the interface name in conky (to eth1) does not fix the indicator

Comment: I assume you also restarted conky to check?

Comment: Yeah, I did restart it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is load up your conky script into a sext editor, and search and replace wlan0 for eth1. also look for other scripts that the main script calls and do the same as this is reasonable common with conky.